# Enter insert mode after search?

Tags: search, insert-mode, nvim

So you're in `Normal` mode, then you press `f` followed by a character, then vim takes you to the next occurrence of that character. When you land on that character you are in `Normal` mode.

My question is how can we make it so that when you land it automatically switches you to `Insert` mode ? at the character landed itself, i.e with `i`.

Comment: The problem with such an approach is that you make it harder to use `f` and `t` as part of other Normal mode sequences and commands. Also, for example, commands such as `dt)` or `ct)` to delete or change until the next `)`. All that just to save a single `i` or `a` key press? Not to mention by bundling these two together you also lose the ability to pick between `i` and `a`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea:

```
nnoremap <expr> f FindInsert('f', 'i')

function FindInsert(find, insert) abort
  const l:char = getchar()->nr2char()
  return printf('%s%s%s', a:find, l:char, a:insert)
endfunction
```

It would then be easy to add `F`/`t`/`T`, or to use `a` instead of `i`, or what have you.

But be aware that when you press `;` or `,`, you won't get this behavior.

Also, I haven't handled counts.

Comment: Actually another one of my mappings threw me off. I infact get this:
`Error detected while processing function FindInsert:
line    1:
E15: Invalid expression: >nr2char()`

Comment: Functional `->` syntax requires a fairly recent Vim version... The equivalent statement without using it is `let l:char = nr2char(getchar())` (`const` is also a recent addition.)